# How to play audio from socket message as arraybuffer to audiosource in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, web-audio-api

I'm sending audio data through audio worklet node and getting response audio as arraybuffer through same socket on socket message event how to play in my device.

**info**

**I'm setting arraybuffer to audiocontext:**

from socket audioData is coming as arraybuffer and i created decodeAudioData function to play the arraybuffer to user connected earphone.

```js
function decodeAudioData(audioData) {
    if (!audioContext) return; 
    audioContext.current.decodeAudioData(audioData, function (decodedData) {
        const channelData = decodedData.getChannelData(0); 
        audioBuffer.copyToChannel(channelData, 0); 
    });
}
```

**error:**

Failed to execute 'decodeAudioData' on 'BaseAudioContext': parameter 1 is not of type

Comment: what's the result?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i updated my question so this is what i'm getting while playing audio data from socket to system